# How does Spy++ construct its process list?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, spy++, window-messages

**TL;DR** -  How does the Spy++ tool really construct its process list?

### Stage

We have an MFC desktop application (running on Windows XP) that is hanging in that it doesn't react to any user input anymore. It *is* redrawn when switching to it via alt-tab however. (It does receive `WM_SETFOCUS`, `WM_ACTIVATE`, etc. It apparently does not receive any mouse or keyboard messages.)

Since the app is hanging in some limbo, we pulled a few process dumps, but these were of little help so far. Enter:

### [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460760.aspx)

We used Spy++ to find the information I gave above about the window messages this application *seems* to be processing. We did this by Opening the [Windows View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460727.aspx) [image: Windows View] and selecting our application Window and in the Messages properties selected `Windows of same process` and `Messages to View` : `Select All`.

*However* we first tried to view all messages of this process by opening the [Processes View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470411.aspx) [image: Processes View] of Spy++ and **our application is not shown in this process list**. Cross checking on another PC where the app is running normally, the process is also normally shown in the processes list of Spy++.

**Can anything about the misbehaving app be inferred from the fact that the process is not shown in Spy++'s Process View**, but the main window of the app is shown in the Windows View. **Why would a process with a main window that is visible not be shown in Spy++'s Processes View?**

The process is listed in Task Manager and in the Attach Process Window of Visual Studio 2005. So these tools apparently use a different method to list processes than Spy++ ... ?

The system where the app is currently hanging is a Windows XP SP2 system and we've used the Spy++ Utility that comes with Visual Studio 2005.

*The behavior does recur occasionally, but only after the App has been running for several days!*

Comment: If your app is run elevated (as administrator), and Spy++ is not elevated, it may not be able to see your process.

Comment: @Aidan - this is on a Windows XP box. No elevation around. :-)

Comment: Given that the process is not responding to all messages, there's a good chance that it is not responding to whatever message is sent by Spy++ to get the Window title, etc. This may cause your process not to appear in the  Processes View either.

Answer (score 2):

Running Vista or later? Your process is probably elevated and Spy++ is not. Newer versions of Spy++ require elevation. So, try elevating Spy++ explicitly and see if that helps.

Comment: Having the same problem, I tried Spy++ both elevated and non-elevated, and my task both elevated and non-elevated. None of the combinations worked. It can't be a bitness problem either, because I have a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course things can be inferred from this. Don't take anything I say too seriously in this context, I'd have to go look at the code. But I believe that Spy goes off and looks at the EnumProcesses API. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629.aspx)

So, if your process isn't showing up there... hrm.

But, what is different between the system where it's working and the one where it's not?

Comment: Not really any *readily known* differences in the systems. That is, with all the hardware the app is communication with, it's very hard to get an exact replica. I just cross checked a bare-bone configuration of the app on my developer machine to have *some* reference point.

Comment: Wouldn't EnumProcesses also be what TaskManager uses?

Answer (score 0):

Spy++ requires the following two values in the registry to be disabled (0) to display the processes/threads list AT ALL:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance

    Disable Performance Counters -> either 0 or not present
```

Was going insane trying to find out why it refused to display them. It's some kind of bad joke - this debugger requires itself a debugger to get it working! Not that WinDBG would display any meaningful info, MS doesn't even provide a symbol file on their symbol server, pfft.

Anyway, maybe it doesn't display processes that have their performance counters disabled, because I think, this can be set on individual basis, at least for services, like:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\.NET CLR Networking\Performance

    Disable Performance Counters
```

So it's basically always a value of the "Performance" subkey. All this stuff is undocumented, it makes use of advapi32.dll functions like "PerfRegQueryValue" and "PerfRegQueryInfoKey"... don't ask me.